# The main form stop responding

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I wrote a function that does alot of mathematical operations and it takes about 10 minutes to finish its work. I tried to call this function via a button on a form (Windows forms application). But the problem now is during the 10 minutes, the main form stops to respond till the function is finishing its work.

How can i solve this... any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might assign a new thread for the calculations so that the form would not have to wait for the calculation to finish to continue execution (i.e. listening to and responding to events etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, while your 10 minute function is working, the rest of the program is not executed. In particular, it cannot execute the rendering. (i.e. making your form respond).

The solution is to use [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you should assign long running tasks to a worker thread or a threadpool thread.

Keep in mind that there are limited numbers of threadpool thread. ALso Windows forms is not thread safe so you should not be directly updating the form from the created thread. You can make use of InvokeRequired.

Answer (score 0):

In this case better to use BackgroundWorker class. Details in following link.

http://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive/